# Print Email Address on home page using SESSION after successful login PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to use SESSION to store my email address and then print it on the home page after successful login. Here is what i have tried but i keep getting an undefined variable error for $Email.  I know the email address is getting stored because it appears in *"inspect element--> Resources --> localhost"*
Here is my code so far. Would appreciate any help or advice on how to correct were i am going wrong.

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Email'])) {

$Email=$_SESSION['Email'];


}
echo "Welcome to your homepage: ".$Email;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the error is gone but i am now just presented with a blank screen. Is this something to do with how i am trying to print the email address out? Here is the code,  <?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Email'])) {

$Email=$_SESSION['Email'];
echo "Welcome to your homepage: ".$Email;

    
}

else {
   $Email = '<unknown>';
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an *undefined variable error* because `$Email` will only be set if the session variable exists.

Fix:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Email'])) {
   $Email = $_SESSION['Email'];
} else {
   $Email = '<unknown>'
}
```

Possible cause: misconception about how session works / about the sequence of request and response events.